# Свойства css left уменьшает ширину блока

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, веб-программирование

Есть данная форма

```css
.b-input-field {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.b-input-field__help-block {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  max-width: 310px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #F6744B;
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
}

.b-input-field__help-block:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -8px);
  z-index: 10;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(246, 116, 75, 1) transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.b-input-field:hover .b-input-field__help-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-input-field">
  <div>
    <label class="b-input-field__label">Label</label>
    <div class="b-input-field__input-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="b-input-field__input " autocomplete="off" name="name" value="">
    </div>
    <p class="b-input-field__help-block">Какой-то текст в блоке, может быть короткий или длинный</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Свойство **left**, которое применяется к контейнеру с текстом центрирует его, но при этом уменьшает ширину на значение, описанное в этом свойстве (50% в данном случае), а нужно, чтобы контейнер был шириной в зависимости от контента, но не шире 310px, что описано свойством **max-width**. Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне, обычно, помогает задание  `left: 0; right: 0;` для выравнивания абсолют блока ан всю ширину контента (родителя):

```css
.b-input-field {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.b-input-field__help-block {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  max-width: 310px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #F6744B;
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, 12px);
}

.b-input-field__help-block:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -8px);
  z-index: 10;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(246, 116, 75, 1) transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.b-input-field:hover .b-input-field__help-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-input-field">
  <div>
    <label class="b-input-field__label">Label</label>
    <div class="b-input-field__input-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="b-input-field__input " autocomplete="off" name="name" value="">
    </div>
    <p class="b-input-field__help-block">Какой-то текст в блоке, может быть короткий или длинный</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: Почему в Вашем примере происходит сужение блока -

```
max-width: 310px;
width: 100%;
```

Нужно указывать ширину `width` для абсолютного блока.

Answer (score 1):

Задать контейнеру параметр `width` например `width: 80%;`

```css
.b-input-field {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.b-input-field__help-block {
  display: none;
  color: white;

  width: 80%; // задаем ширину блоку

  max-width: 310px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #F6744B;
  opacity: 0.85;
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 12px);
}

.b-input-field__help-block:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -8px);
  z-index: 10;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(246, 116, 75, 1) transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.b-input-field:hover .b-input-field__help-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-input-field">
  <div>
    <label class="b-input-field__label">Label</label>
    <div class="b-input-field__input-wrap">
      <input type="text" class="b-input-field__input " autocomplete="off" name="name" value="">
    </div>
    <p class="b-input-field__help-block">Какой-то текст в блоке, может быть короткий или длинный</p>
  </div>
</div>
```